# Android Smooth timer progressbar with custom shape

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar, android-xml, android-custom-drawable

I am trying to make a time progress bar in my app to show 35 seconds

i added a countdown timer to it but the problem is it changes values on each second but i want the progress bar to change smoothly

here is my code:

```
mCountDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(35000,1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        i--;
        mProgressBar.setProgress(i);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        i--;
        mProgressBar.setProgress(i);
        wrongAnswer(false);
    }
};
```

i tried using animation but it was a little bit hard for me and i did not figure out what to do.

is there any way to do so and make a smooth progress bar in a right way?

***EDIT:***
I reduced value of `countDownInterval` to 40ms , but now it acts weird on different devices. although timer is ok and ends in 17ms, progress bar acts different and sometimes ends in the middle, some times before finishing and ... 
is that possible that `progressbar` does not have enough time to change the progress every 40ms and so my problem happens?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `countDownInterval` field of the timer's [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#CountDownTimer(long,%20long)) to a value that isn't 1000ms? Try a smaller number to call the `onTick()` method more frequently.

Comment: that worked for me, but i'm asking is that a right way to implement a what i need? and another question, do you hame any idea what should i do do change the shape of the progressbar?

Comment: i reduced `countDownInterval` to 40ms , but the progress bar acts different in some devices! i think the problem is that timer acts weird because of small counddown interval and it doesn't have the time to update progress bar that fast and problem happens. my progressbar sometimes ends in the middle of the progress, althow the timer is finished!